# How to import a cached numba function without a Python definition

Tags: python, caching, import, numba, jit

Consider the following function in `numba`, which just serves as an example:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit('float64(float64[::1])', cache=True)
def total (x):
    ''' Sum the elements of an array. '''

    total = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        total += x[i]

    return total

x = np.arange(100,dtype=np.float64)
print(total(x))
```

Since I have specified the `cache=True` option, two files are created in the `__pycache__` folder, one `.nbc` file and one `.nbi` file. I assume that these files contain all (compiled) information about the function. Let's say I delete the Python file that defines the function (i..e, the above code).

**Can I still use compiled/cached functions? In other words, can I import them without having the original .py file that defined them?**

Comment: The .nbc file contains the compiled code for the function, so it can be imported directly into a program. The .nbi file contains the type information for the function, which is necessary for calling the function correctly. So both files must be present for the function to work correctly.

Comment: Does this help [ahead of time compiling](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/pycc.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael Szczesny's comment about [ahead of time compilation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/pycc.html) is exactly what I wanted. To make it work, I have adapted the code as follows:

```py
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('my_module')

@cc.export('total', 'float64(float64[::1])')
def total (x):
    ''' Sum the elements of an array. '''

    total = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        total += x[i]

    return total

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

After running this file, a binary module file (`.pyd`) is saved in the directory and you can use it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from my_module import total

x = np.arange(100,dtype=np.float64)
print(total(x))
```

Comment: Note that AFAIK ahead-of-time compilation does not supports some performance-related flags like fast-math and parallel loops. If you need this, then using Cython may be a better alternative (especially if you want to create a Python package).